# UIButtons are greyed out when view is re-loaded (iOS 7.1 simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, xcode6, ios-simulator

I've set my Deployment Target to 7.1+ and downloaded the iOS 7.1 simulators for xcode6. When I test the app on a '7.1' device, anytime I navigate back to a view that has already loaded, all the user elements are grey instead of blue.

The bug is between the initial table view and a child table view. How I navigate out of the child view doesn't affect the bug (either saves or discards changes made to core data). The UIButtons are still enabled, it's just as if the color were set to grey.

I'm not sure what code would be worth posting, I'm assuming its something basic? I originally set the deployment target to 8.0. I have since reset the launch image to support the 4" screen but that's about it.

[Initial View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuWXq.png)
[Second Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfp0p.png)

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen similar issues with modal presentations in the simulator.  I'm bet your problem doesn't manifest on an actual device.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't got ahold of a phone with iOS 7 yet,  but I'll check it and hope that's the case!!